# Split string into text part and URL part

Tags: php, string

I am developing social networking site where users can post links with or without text. If the user posts a link like this:

```
downloaded image from www.google.com
```

I want to post this as `downloaded image from` as simple text and `www.google.com` as a tag. I've done this using the `explode` function like this:

```
$desc_res = explode("www.", $desc);
$post_desc = str_replace("https://", "", $desc_res[1]);
$description = $desc_res[0]."<a target=_blank href=".'http://'.$post_desc.">".$post_desc."</a>";
```

It is working fine. My problem is how to do the same thing if user posts without `www` or `http` like this:

```
downloaded image from google.com
```

I've tried so many solutions but nothing helped me. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can add a check with `strpos` or `preg_match`.

Comment: i've tried it but its not working our. can u pls give me example?

Comment: The [parse_url — Parse a URL and return its components](https://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function maybe useful to determine what is provided in the given _Url_?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
    echo strrchr("Hello world!","world");
    ?>
    o/p: world!
```

Comment: i want to devide the string in two parts first one will be downloaded image from and second one will be www.google.com

Comment: if you wont to  divide the string in two parts than use explode method

Comment: i know i've to use explode method but the thing is my string is like this downloaded image from google.com. if my string is like this downloaded image from and second one will be www.google.com then i should be exploding it with www but in my case the url is without www http or https.

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
if (strpos('www', $str) !== false) {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: i don't have www http or https in my string

Comment: You just have to add the conditions likewise.

Answer (score -1):

I've done it on my own by using regexp pattern matching. If user anything as post with text or link it will give the result. Below is my code.

```
$reg_exUrl = "/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
$text = "http://www.google.com The text you want to google.com filter goes here. google.com";
preg_match_all($reg_exUrl, $text, $matches);
$usedPatterns = array();
foreach($matches[0] as $pattern){
  if(!array_key_exists($pattern, $usedPatterns)){
    $usedPatterns[$pattern]=true;
    $text = str_replace($pattern, "<a href=http://$pattern>$pattern</a>", $text);   
  }
}
echo $text;
```

The output should be:

```
http://www.google.com/ The text you want to google.com filter goes here google.com
```

Comment: Not quite there. I get nested links when I try your code.